# Connecting iOS app to a mysql database connected to a website that is currently online

Tags: php, python, ios, mysql

I have already created a website with a mysql database. Now, I am attempting to create an IOS app that will connect to the same database that my website "talks to". All of the tutorials I have seen have relied exclusively upon PHP and have walked through the process of creating the database. My website was not written with PHP, so I am completely lost on how I get PHP to help me in this case. I'm new to all this, so I am not sure what information is helpful, but so you know:

The website templates were written in HTML and CSS,
views page (functionality) written in python,
Flask is the microframework, and
pymysql is the ORM

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, connecting mobile app to connect to a database directly is a bad bad idea. You never want to expose your database directly to the internet. A better idea would be to have an API using python that you can call form your mobile app to retrieve required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Flask` then this is how you need to go through - there are other ways, but I would go for this -

1. Install `Flask REST API` to expose rest api from your site. You can get the documentation here - http://www.flaskapi.org/
2. Expose required API's from your website using flash rest api
3. Consume those API's with your mobile application.

NOTE: Don't ever expose your database directly to client side. BAD IDEA. Always use a middleware, could be php, python, .net - does not matter what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Glad you got this answer in before the question was marked as too broad, as I needed a general answer since I am just learning all this.